# Sitecore displays multiple 'en' language options on publish

Tags: sitecore

We have an instance of Sitecore 7.5 (141003) running on an internal dev server (we're slowly going through the process of upgrading).

We have an odd issue where when you publish an item as an admin you see the following under the "Publishing Language" heading:

- Select all
- English
- English
- English

Under sitecore > System > Languages we have a single 'en' item, but with the following code we see that we have three 'en' items (Item ID matches the item under System > Languages) and two 'en-us' items (no Item ID):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="true" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <script runat="server">
            void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current == null || Sitecore.Context.Database == null)
                {
                    Response.Write("No context.");
                    return;
                }

                var languages = Sitecore.Data.Managers.LanguageManager.GetLanguages(Sitecore.Context.Database);

                foreach (var language in languages)
                {
                    Response.Write(Sitecore.Data.Managers.LanguageManager.GetLanguageItemId(language, Sitecore.Context.Database) + "<br />");
                    Response.Write(language.CultureInfo + "<br />");
                }
            }
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Additionally, if I run the following query against the Master database, I see only the one item.

```
USE XXXSitecore_Master
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM Items
WHERE ID = 'AF584191-45C9-4201-8740-5409F4CF8BDD'
```

Since this is a development server database backup and restores have been used to get it current with another server, but I believe packaging was also used.

I'm confused why there are multiple versions of 'en' with the same Item ID being returned.

How could we go about finding where these additional English languages are coming from, so that we could ultimately go through and clean them up?

### Edit 1

Publish Site displays the same three English options.

Looking at the Language section in the Versions tab, *English: English* is displayed three times, with 12 versions for each (and all three highlighted), and then *English (United States): English (United States)* is displayed twice, with 2 versions for each.

Looking at the Versions, we have 10 through 1, and then 1 twice more. The date and last person to update are the same. So there are 12 versions, but version 1 is listed three times. Unable to look at the database at this time to see what I can find out about the three version 1 instances.

Comment: Make sure you all databases (except Core, which contains the client languages and should not be touched) have the same set of languages. You can do this by publishing System/Languages.

What happens if you do a site publish (instead of item publish). What languages appear then? I wonder if your item is not versioned in languages that are not present any more.

Comment: Good questions. I've added an Edit 1 section to the bottom of the original question that should answer your questions. And yet another oddity since there's essentially three version 1 of an item.

Comment: First, try clearing the cache (/sitecore/admin/cache.aspx). The "LanguageProvider - Languages" key stores the languages, so there could be a problem there. The other thing to check would be your config files (/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx) -- check the <dataproviders> section vs a vanilla install. It's possible Sitecore is looping through multiple data providers for the same database, or a defective custom provider is being used. Finally, open the "sitecore/templates/System/Language" template, and from the Navigate ribbon, click on Links to see all the items that are based on that template.

Comment: Belatedly, it appears to be an issue with a custom data provider. Now to work with the developer to determine what within the provider is causing the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We had similar issue in Sitecore 8 (after adding/removing languages several times and had an exception in our code at the same time). Have no clear answer why that happened but I've created that 'virtual language' item again and then deleted it properly. That solved the issue. BTW: as far as I remember Sitecore did not allowed to create new language as it was 'existing' so we've created language item in clean Sitecore and moved it with package.